# Outer div can't has its own height

Tags: html, css, position, height, absolute

I have a outer div that calls `#slide` and it has some image in it. Each images have `position: absolute;` for resizing themselves automatically inside of the `#slide` div.

The problem is when I set like that, the `#slide`‘s height becomes 0 then I can’t put the contents below the div.

Right now the text looks like behind the image. I want to put the text under the `#slide`.

Is there any ways to fix this problem?

```css
#slide {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#slide-list {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 1170px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
}
.slide-l-quarter {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% / 4);
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
.slide-l-quarter img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
#text {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<section id="slide">
  <div id="slide-list">
    <ul class="slide-l-quarter">
   <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dsey4pc.jpg" alt="">
    </ul>
    <ul class="slide-l-quarter">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dsey4pc.jpg" alt="">
    </ul>
    <ul class="slide-l-quarter">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dsey4pc.jpg" alt="">
    </ul>
    <ul class="slide-l-quarter">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dsey4pc.jpg" alt="">
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="text">
    Some Text
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: `absolute` elements do not contribute to the height of the container. Can you not use `position:relative` for the images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you used `absolute` position for `img` tags, it does not contribute any height to its parent.

I removed the `position: absolute` from the `img` & also change your `ul` to `li` wrapped by an `ul` tag.

```css
#slide {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#slide-list {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 1170px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

.slide-l-quarter {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% / 4);
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.slide-l-quarter img {  
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#text {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<section id="slide">
  <ul id="slide-list">
    <li class="slide-l-quarter">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dsey4pc.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="slide-l-quarter">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dsey4pc.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="slide-l-quarter">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dsey4pc.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="slide-l-quarter">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dsey4pc.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="text">
    Some Text
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   img {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0px;
      top: 0px;
      z-index: -1;
    }
```

add this to your css